# Pylint only Global evaluation

Tags: python, pylint

In pylint I use this command `--reports=n` to disable the reports, but now I don't see the Global evaluation more.

Is possible enable only the Global evaluation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't, Global Evaluation is part of the reports and with **--reports=n** you disable all the reports .

Comment: Sad. Would be a nice feature :( because run the pylint using pre-commit.com and the report is too long, but without report, I lost a cool feature  whose is my score.

Answer (score 4):

This post is quite old but here's the current solution:

To disable EVERYTHING other than the Global evaluation section, you must

```
--disable=RP0001
--disable=RP0002
--disable=RP0003
--disable=RP0101
--disable=RP0401
--disable=RP0701
--disable=RP0801
```

The link shared in another answer now seems to be up to date. http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/all-codes

Note: this still leaves the portion shown below:

```
Report
======
XXX statements analyzed.
```

My solution is to capture the standard out and standard error and eliminate the Report section while capturing the score from the Global evaluation and printing the score elsewhere on my own.

I am writing a wrapper around Pylint and pep8 and some internal Python quality checks (company headers, etc.) where this problem came up.

Comment: I'm have the same problem setup a git hook using pre-commit.com. I think this can be works.

Answer (score 3):

You can use e.g. --disable=RP0701 to disable the Raw metrics part of the report.

This (outdated) list can help to find the IDs of blocks you would like to suppress:

http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/all-codes

Note that the report IDs have been renamed from Rxxxx to RPxxxx!

Answer (score 0):

As systempunttoout said, this is currently not possible. But you can ask for this on the python-projects@logilab.org mailing list, and submitting a patch is a very good way of getting that feature soon. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I can nearly just get the Global evaluation.
To eliminate everything but Duplication and Global evaluation add;

```
--disable=RP0401 --disable=RP0001 --disable=RP0002 --disable=RP0003 --disable=RP0101 --disable=RP0101 --disable=RP0701
```

Being unable to disable the duplication report seems to be a bug;
http://www.logilab.org/ticket/63424

Answer (score 0):

You could use AWK:

```
pylint generators.py | awk '$0 ~ /Your code/ || $0 ~ /Global/ {print}'
```

I got this printout:

No config file found, using default configuration

```
Global evaluation
Your code has been rated at 8.12/10 (previous run: 8.12/10, +0.00)
```